# Intervention Image - Unable to init from given url - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention

I'm using [laravel intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) for resize images in laravel, but when I'm trying to initialize with Image::make with a thumbnail url from google cloud storage I get this error

> Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException Unable to init from
> given url

this is my code

```
    if ($logo != null){
    $largeLogoUrl = $logo->google_url;
    $largeLogo = Image::make($largeLogoUrl);
    $smallLogoUrl = $logo->thumbnail_url;
    $smallLogo = Image::make($smallLogoUrl);
    }
```

with $largeLogo it's all ok, not problem, it is also from google cloud storage link, when I'm doing a debug the error message appear in the line of `$smallLogo = Image::make($smallLogo);`

this is the value from $largeLogo and $smallLogo

```
$largeLogo = https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/A_b-UKp70TuAFetX6dQcaGmJcl32chMiXFDX8oYd6w_Hu1iR13LJfhs99OJyfFQX2UpRPzdva1I1-2L1=s0
$smallLogo = https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNF9Au8QW_vkefTfsrRlmR4IOf87EfwDgtvG1w_=s300
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this one out?